# JavaScript redirect after answering all quizs

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have this code it works perfect for my purpose BUT I only want the users to be redirected only if they answers both questions right , I am no expert in javascript , How can I fix this ( if answers both questions right   location.assign("https://www.google.com");

```js
 <!-- Hide from old browsers
var A // the first number
var B // the second number
A = 1000
B = 1000
document.writeln(" <p> Q1 - What does " + A + " + " + B + " equal?</p>")
// Function
//   checkAnswer
// Description
//   Checks the user's answers
function checkAnswer()
{
  var answer = document.fillin.answer.value
  if (answer != A+B) {
    alert(
      "Sorry, " + answer + " does not equal " + 
      A + " + " + B + ".")
    docment.fillin.answer.value = ""
  }
  else  {
  location.assign("https://www.google.com");   }
} // checkAnswer
// -->
 <!-- Hide from old browsers
var A // the first number
var B // the second number
A = 2000
B = 1000
document.writeln(" <p>Q2 - What does " + A + " + " + B + " equal?</p>")
// Function
//   checkAnswer
// Description
//   Checks the user's answer2s
function checkAnswer()
{
  var answer2 = document.fillin.answer2.value
  if (answer2 != A+B) {
    alert(
      "Sorry, " + answer2 + " does not equal " + 
      A + " + " + B + ".")
    docment.fillin.answer2.value = ""
  }
  else  {
  location.assign("https://www.google.com");   }
} // checkAnswer
// -->
```

```html
<form name="fillin">
answer 1 <input type="text" name="answer" value=""> <br>
answer 2<input type="text" name="answer2" value=""> <br>
<input type="button" name="check" value="Check" onclick="checkAnswer()">
</form>
```

Comment: You use the same variables for both cases - and declaring the same function `checkAnswer()` twice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using A and B for both questions you should use different variables for each and then check them separately.

```js
var A = 1000
var B = 1000
var C = 2000
var D = 1000
document.writeln(" <p> Q1 - What does " + A + " + " + B + " equal?</p>")          
document.writeln(" <p>Q2 - What does " + C + " + " + D + " equal?</p>")

function checkAnswer() {
  var answer2 = document.fillin.answer2.value
  var answer = document.fillin.answer.value
  if (answer != A + B) {
     alert("Sorry, " + answer + " does not equal " + A + " + " + B + ".")
     document.fillin.answer.value = ""
  } else if (answer2 != C + D) {    
    alert("Sorry, " + answer2 + " does not equal " + C + " + " + D + ".")
    document.fillin.answer2.value = ""
  }
  else {
    location.assign("https://www.google.com");
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="fillin">
answer 1 <input type="text" name="answer" value=""> <br>
answer 2<input type="text" name="answer2" value=""> <br>
<input type="button" name="check" value="Check" onclick="checkAnswer()">
</form>
```

Comment: your code is good the alert works for both inputs  , but it didn't redirect to the link even if they both right answer

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working as a snippet at all did you try it locally I tested just the location.assign("https://www.google.com"); locally  and it works but didn't recreate the whole thing and test it

Comment: your code helped me to fix it thanks a lot :) I removed the { before   var answer = document.fillin.answer2.value
 and }before else and it worked

Comment: Sorry was working on a phone couldn't debug it all happy to help

Comment: Cleaned up the code a bit sorry for the sloppiness yesterday